# Windows: How to view *.mvb extension files?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have mvb extension files for an ebook I had downloaded. One file per page of the book. Which program can I use for viewing these files?

Comment: Is there a .hlp file somewhere? Maybe you're supposed to use winhlp32.exe to open the .hlp, which will refer to each mvb files

Answer (score 1):

`.mvb` proper is an ancient format used by Microsoft Multimedia Viewer for Windows 3.1 (!). E.g. [here's a book about it](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1878739603) from 1994.

So, chances are, you have something different.

You can look inside the file for any keywords to look up (e.g. binary formats typically start with some specific "magic bytes" for easy identification). If it's for some specific e-book, you can look it up in its documentation or wherever you got the file from.

Answer (score 0):

[***.MVB**](http://www.file-extensions.org/mvb-file-extension) file extension *(Multimedia Viewer book file)* are commonly used to store Video or Audio information.

Not sure if you can view these files using **RealPlayer**, but it's worth a try!

If the file is not corrupted, then it should play.